# How do you tell if a datetime is am or pm using luxon / moment?

Tags: javascript, luxon

This:

```
import {DateTime} from "luxon";

[
   "2022-05-30T11:00:00Z",
   "2022-05-30T11:00:00+01:00",
   "2022-05-30T11:00:00-01:00",
].map(raw => {
   var sysTime = DateTime.fromISO(raw);
   var amPm = sysTime.hour < 12 ? "am" : "pm";
   console.log(`${raw}: ${amPm}`);
});
```

Emits this:

```
2022-05-30T11:00:00Z: pm
2022-05-30T11:00:00+01:00: pm
2022-05-30T11:00:00-01:00: pm
```

Which is clearly wrong.

Yes, it *is* wrong, because `2022-05-30T11:00:00+01:00` is not `pm` in *that timezone*.

Since luxon automatically stores `SystemZone`, you have to explicitly convert it to correct timezone, *if* you happen to know what it is, for example:

```
[
   "2022-05-30T11:00:00Z",
   "2022-05-30T11:00:00+01:00",
   "2022-05-30T11:00:00-01:00",
].map(raw => {
   var sysTime = DateTime.fromISO(raw);
   var realTime = sysTime.setZone('UTC+1'); // <---- explicit
   var amPm = realTime.hour < 12 ? "am" : "pm";
   console.log(`${raw}: ${amPm}`);
});
```

Emits this:

```
2022-05-30T11:00:00Z: pm <---- still wrong
2022-05-30T11:00:00+01:00: am <--- correct
2022-05-30T11:00:00-01:00: pm
```

So, what's the right way to do this?

...and to be clear, I'm not trying to parse these date times *without a timezone*, I'm trying to parse them in a way that preserves the "UTC+X" timezone that is *in the raw date string*.

Is that possible?

Comment: @Doug did you not read https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromiso?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245148/discussion-on-question-by-doug-how-do-you-tell-if-a-datetime-is-am-or-pm-using-l).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use: `setZone: true` in `fromISO`.

```
import {DateTime} from "luxon";

[
   "2022-05-30T11:00:00Z",
   "2022-05-30T11:00:00+01:00",
   "2022-05-30T11:00:00-01:00",
].map(raw => {
   var sysTime = DateTime.fromISO(raw, {setZone: true});
   var amPm = sysTime.hour < 12 ? "am" : "pm";
   console.log(`${raw}: ${amPm}`);
});
```